# Почему значение функции не сохраняется?

Tags: javascript

```js
fire = () => {
  console.log('fire');
}

const once = function(fn) {
  var show = true;

  return function() {
    if (show) {
      fn();
      show = false;
    }
  }
}

const f = once(fire)
const result = f()

f()
f()
f()
f()

console.log(result);

// вывод Fire 
// undefined
```

Comment: что не сохраняется где? Анонимная функция ничего не возвращает, как, впрочем, и стрелочная.

Comment: в result не сохраняется и не выводит значение const f = fire(once)

Comment: *функция `f` ничего не возвращает*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваша анонимная функция ничего не возвращает, как, впрочем, и стрелочная.
Функция f ничего не возвращает.

Вот как должно быть:

```js
fire = () => {
  console.log('fire');
  return 'fire';
}

const once = function(fn) {
  var show = true;

  return function() {
    if (show) {
      show = false;
      return fn();
    }
  }
}

const f = once(fire)
const result = f()

f()
f()
f()
f()

console.log(result);
```